# SQL using If Not Null on a Concatenation

Tags: sql, null, concatenation

If I have the table

[image]

```
SELECT (Firstname || '-' || Middlename || '-' || Surname)  AS example_column
FROM example_table
```

This will display Firstname-Middlename-Surname e.g.

```
John--Smith
Jane-Anne-Smith
```

The second one (Jane’s) displays correct, however since John doesn’t have a middlename, I want it to ignore the second dash.

How could I put a sort of IF Middlename = NULL statement in so that it would just display John-Smith

Comment: You need to tag the **RDBMS** you are using. Generally *string concatenation* differs with each vendor

Comment: Based on the popular four database, it's either Oracle or PostgreSQL

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here would be my suggestions:

PostgreSQL and other SQL databases where `'a' || NULL IS NULL`, then use [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
SELECT firstname || COALESCE('-' || middlename, '') || '-' || surname ...
```

Oracle and other SQL databases where `'a' || NULL = 'a'`:

```
SELECT first name || DECODE(middlename, NULL, '', '-' || middlename) || '-' || surname...
```

I like to go for conciseness.  Here it is not very interesting to any maintenance programmer whether the middle name is empty or not.  CASE switches are perfectly fine, but they are bulky.  I'd like to avoid repeating the same column name ("middle name") where possible.

As @Prdp noted, the answer is RDBMS-specific.  What is specific is whether the server treats a zero-length string as being equivalent to `NULL`, which determines whether concatenating a `NULL` yields a `NULL` or not.

Generally `COALESCE` is most concise for PostgreSQL-style empty string handling, and `DECODE (*VALUE*, NULL, ''...` for Oracle-style empty string handling.

Comment: `COALESCE('-' || NULLIF(middlename,''), '')` worked for me since in my case middlename comprised of empty strings even though it was showing `NULL` in the output.

Comment: The first option works great for SQLite, thanks!

Answer (score 37):

If you use Postgres, `concat_ws()` is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT concat_ws('-', Firstname, Middlename, Surname)  AS example_column
FROM example_table
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8812

To treat empty strings or strings that only contain spaces like `NULL` use `nullif()`:

```
 SELECT concat_ws('-', Firstname, nullif(trim(Middlename), ''), Surname)  AS example_column
 FROM example_table
```

Comment: based on the question, the answer is not complete. the null  middle name should not have a double dash

Comment: @MichaelBuen: it won't. `concat_ws()` will take care of that.

Comment: +1 neat :) i just tested your code with empty string (not null), which is not in the question anyway, that's why i thought that didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelBuen: you could use `nullif(middlename, '')` to treat an empty string as null

Comment: Yes, i applied NULLIF on my answer. I forgot to apply the same on your concat_ws answer and tested on sqlfiddle, hence I thought concat_ws didn't work.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Also note that for **impala** and **hive**, `SELECT concat_ws('-', 'a', null, 'c')  AS example_column;` returns `null` in Impala and `a-c` in Hive.

Answer (score 2):

This approach [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94a07/2):

```
select first_name || coalesce('-' || middle_name, '') || '-' || last_name 
from t;
```

Output:

```
|        ?column? |
|-----------------|
|      john-smith |
| jane-anne-smith |
```

**UPDATE**

Live code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d5a1f/1

Just as my inkling, someone will give a scenario that is not in the question. So to make it work with empty middle name. Just add a nullif for empty string:

```
select first_name || coalesce('-' || nullif(middle_name,'') , '') || '-' || last_name 
from t;
```

Output:

```
|        ?column? |
|-----------------|
|      john-smith |
|      obi-kinobi |
| jane-anne-smith |
```

Comment: Try again: `with cte as  (
Select 'Luke' as FirstName, 'Jedi' as MiddleName, 'Master' as lastName from dual
UNion all
Select 'Darth' as FirstName, 'IamYourFather' as MiddleName, 'Vader' as lastName from dual
UNion all
Select 'Wierd' as FirstName, 'VaderSomeDaylater' as MiddleName, 'Yankovick' as lastName from dual
UNION ALL
Select 'Obi' as FirstName, '' as MiddleName, 'Wankanobi' as lastName from dual

Union all
Select 'Michael' as FirstName, 'NoSoupForYou' as MiddleName, 'Buen' as lastName from dual
) select firstname || coalesce('-' || middlename, '') || '-' || lastname from cte;`

Comment: PostgreSQL style empty string handling

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using `case statement`

```
select case Middlename is not null then (Firstname || '-' || Middlename || '-' || Surname) 
    else (Firstname || '-' || Surname) end AS example_column
from ....
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a viable option:

```
SELECT FirstName || '-' || ISNULL(MiddleName + '-', '') || Surname
```

Since a NULL concatenated with a string yields a NULL, we can attempt to build our sub-string and replace a NULL with an empty string, which is then concatenated to the next part of the name.

This assumes that FirstName and Surname are always NOT NULL, but you could apply the same logic to then as well.

Comment: If your RDBMS does not have an ISNULL construct, it probably has a COALESCE, which works similarly.

Comment: Doesn't work when Middlename contains an empty string

Comment: Alas, you are correct, but there was no mention of an empty string in the original question (see @Michael Buen's response to the same situation).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REPLACE` (if Oracle)

```
SELECT
   REPLACE(Firstname || '-' || Middlename || '-' || Surname,'--','-') 
   AS example_column
FROM example_table;
```

Warning: I've assumed there is no valid name with `-` as first or last character.

---

**For downvoter**

OP clearly said that:

> ```
> SELECT (Firstname || '-' || Middlename || '-' || Surname)  AS example_column
> FROM example_table
> ```
>
> This will display Firstname-Middlename-Surname e.g.
>
> **John--Smith**

So:

1. `Middlename` is blank: `''` this solution works in `SQLite/PostgreSQL/Oracle`
2. `Middlename` is `NULL` and OP probably uses [`Oracle`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)

> **Although Oracle treats zero-length character strings as nulls, concatenating a zero-length character string with another operand always results in the other operand, so null can result only from the concatenation of two null strings.**

`||` concatentaion operator:

```
 -- PostgreSQL/SQLite
 SELECT 'sth' || NULL
 -- NULL


 -- Oracle
 SELECT 'sth' || NULL
 -- sth
```

Comment: Note this assumes Oracle NULL string = '' operation.

Comment: For downvoter please leave a comment, why this solution is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement

```
select Firstname 
      || case when Middlename <> '' Then '-'||Middlename  else '' END 
      || case when Surname<> '' Then '-'||Surname else '' END
```

As per your sample data I have check for `empty string`. To check `NULL` use `Middlename IS NOT NULL` instead of `Middlename <> ''`

Answer (score 0):

- The `NULLIF` expression reduces blank `Middlename` to `NULL`
- Concatenating `'-'` with a `NULL` will always return `NULL`
- The`VALUE` expression replaces `NULL`s with an empty string

_

```
SELECT Firstname || VALUE( '-' || NULLIF('Middlename',''),'') || '-' || Surname'  
       AS example_column
FROM example_table
```

Comment: same as my answer some 21 minutes ago, except you use VALUE instead of COALESCE

Comment: Which DBMS supports that `value()` function?

Comment: I was assuming DB2. But the solution can be adapted `COALESCE()`, `ISNULL()` are alternate functions for other engines.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for SQL Server (MSSQL) this worked for me:

```
SELECT ([Firstname] + '-' + COALESCE([Middlename]+'-', '') + [Surname])
AS example_column 
FROM example_table
```

If you also want to skip the empty string (as I did) add a `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT ([Firstname] + '-' + COALESCE(NULLIF([Middlename]+'-', '-'),'') + [Surname])
AS example_column 
FROM example_table
```