# How to conditionally exclude a column from a concatenation?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In Oracle SQL, I'm attempting to concatenate an address from several fields that look like this

```
CREATE TABLE sql_test_c 
( 
    ADDRESS_LINE varchar(255), 
    ADDRESS_LINE_2 varchar(255), 
    ADDRESS_LINE_3 varchar(255),
    CITY_NAME varchar(255),
    STATE_CODE varchar(255),
    ZIP_CODE varchar(255)
); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_c (ADDRESS_LINE, ADDRESS_LINE_2, CITY_NAME, STATE_CODE, ZIP_CODE) VALUES ('Business Name', '123 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '12345');
```

Unfortunately, in my dataset there are a lot of addresses that don't have anything in ADDRESS_LINE_3 (like this one) so when I use

```
SELECT ADDRESS_LINE || ', ' || 
       ADDRESS_LINE_2 || ', ' ||
       ADDRESS_LINE_3 || ', ' ||
       CITY_NAME || ', ' ||
       STATE_CODE || ' ' ||
       ZIP_CODE
FROM sql_test_c;
```

I end up with

```
Business Name, 123 Main Street, , Seattle, WA 12345
```

With those two commas between the address and the City. Is there a way to include columns dynamically if they are null or not? I've tried various forms of coalesce like this one:

```
SELECT ADDRESS_LINE || ', ' || 
       ADDRESS_LINE_2 || ', ' ||
       COALESCE(ADDRESS_LINE_3 || ', ', '') ||
       CITY_NAME || ', ' ||
       STATE_CODE || ' ' ||
       ZIP_CODE
FROM sql_test_c;
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: I wouldn't do that; it makes life hell for the downstream person or code to process the result, as they now have to work out how many addresses are in the CSV.  Just leave the column empty.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330260/sql-using-if-not-null-on-a-concatenation

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is going to a UI so it looks bad to have , , in the middle of the address.

Comment: @JoshEller that answer works great thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `coalesce()` doesn't work because Oracle treats `NULL` as an empty string with the `||` operator.

You can get around this using `case`:

```
SELECT ADDRESS_LINE || ', ' || 
       ADDRESS_LINE_2 || ', ' ||
       (CASE WHEN ADDRESS_LINE_3 IS NOT NULL THEN ADDRESS_LINE_3 || ', ' END) ||
       CITY_NAME || ', ' ||
       STATE_CODE || ' ' ||
       ZIP_CODE
FROM sql_test_c;
```

Comment: This answer works, although DECODE(ADDRESS_LINE_3, NULL, '', ', ' || ADDRESS_LINE_3) does the same thing slightly cleaner

Comment: @rdennis42 . . . I for one strongly disagree.  `decode()` is a bespoke Oracle function.  `CASE` is the standard SQL syntax for conditional expressions.  I generally much prefer standards.